# show tempdata message of mvc5 as bootbox alert message

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, bootbox

I am new at MVC and I want to show an alert message from the Controller tempdata as bootbox alert message

How can it be done? Please somebody help me with an example

Answer (score 0):

Say you have `TempData["Message"]`

In your view assign it to some `hiddenField` as below

```
@{
var message=TempData["Message"] as string;
}
<input type="hidden" value="@message" id="hdnMessage"/>
```

Now write a `document.ready` function and check if the hidden field has value and if yes show your message as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if($("#hdnMessage").val()!="")
     {
         var msg=$("#hdnMessage").val();
         bootbox.alert(msg);
         $("#hdnMessage").val('');//empty the value so that it won't show everytime
     }
});
```

Comment: You can mark it as answer if it helped you so that other users coming in search of the same problem will get the answer too!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `<script>` tag is used in the view, you can directly inject the value from `TempData` into JavaScript. Something like this would work:

```
@if(TempData.ContainsKey("Message"))
{
    <script>
        $(function(){ 
            bootbox.alert('@TempData["Message"]');
        });
    </script>
}
```

This **won't** work in a .js file, as those aren't parsed by the Razor engine.

You could put this in a partial view, or include it somewhere in _Layout, or simply use it in the view you're currently working in. The only important bit it to remember that it needs to be rendered after jQuery, bootstrap.js, and bootbox.js.

Comment: my question here is after i click bootbox alert again i want the tempdata message to be displayed as bootbox alert is it possible

Comment: @SanjayChaudhary I'm not sure what you're asking. Please update your question to include what you're trying to do, preferably with code you're tried.

Comment: Thank You For Your Reply i have made it work i just made it display in my view with out using any alert